# Classify Pixel using Deep Learning (strange result)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, deep-learning

I've started to use a new version of deep learning tools for ArcGIS Pro.

Then I received a strange results on my classification:

[image]

The main libraries that i used are:
arcgis=1.8.2
scikit-image=0.15.0
pillow=6.2.2
libtiff=4.0.10
fastai=1.0.60
pytorch=1.4.0
torchvision=0.5.0
tensorflow-gpu=2.1.0

When I go back to my old libraries:

arcgis=1.8.2
scikit-image=0.15.0
pillow=6.2.2
libtiff=4.0.10
fastai=1.0.54
pytorch=1.1.0
torchvision=0.3.0
tensorflow-gpu=1.14.0

All back to normal, and I received such result:

[image]

Some details:

1. I used the same type of imagery, same version of ArcGIS Pro (2.5),  same deep learning model. Only change was libraries pytorch (tensorflow).
2. Also tried on the different type of imagery (simple RGB, non multispectral). Result the same - on new pytorch and tensorflow - result with artifacts as on first figure.
3. Even tried to train a new model on new libraries. Training comes with no problems. But classification causes the same strange result as mentioned before.

The new libraries I was installed such as mentioned in recommendation by installing deep learning tools or installing Python API for deep learning.

I think such kind of result may cause that the new version of tensorflow or pytorch had different interpretation of functions for segmentation. But may be its an another cause. I want to clarify that.

Can you help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I've localize my problem. Problem was in fastai 1.0.60. Using fastai 1.0.54 with pytorch 1.4.0 removes strange result as on first picture, all back to normal. But unfortunately I still don't get it what cause a problem with fastai 1.0.60 on my PC.